# Disparadores falsos durante la ejecución de un formulario HTTP doPost(e)

Tags: google-apps-script, aplicación-web, trigger

Buen día para todos, de antemano agradezco la ayuda, hace un tiempo que estoy realizando programas con el lenguaje appscript, en este caso realice un formulario para que un usuario pudiera ingresar cierta información y luego con un botón enviar la información para así hacer un llamado de una API, pero hace unos días he comenzado a tener el problema de que se generan "disparadores falsos" durante la ejecución del programa, no es un error recurrente y tengo comprobaciones como que no se pueda pulsar el botón más de una vez, sin embargo no he tenido éxito en poder evitar que se generen dichos disparadores que me generan dobles procesos, he comprobado que cuando sucede el tiempo entre disparadores siempre es de dos minutos.

Buscando en la documentación encontré algo sobre la función flush, la cual adicione al inicio del método doPost(e) que es donde hago todo el proceso, ya que pensaba más que era un error por la API y la forma como estoy procesando la información, pero buscando problemas similares me encontré que con los formularios se generan los disparadores falsos, pero no logro plantear como podría hacer una comprobación para evitarlos.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Buen día, el problema es que se envían dos veces el trigger al presionar el botón cuando solo debería ser uno, el botón tiene la condición de que solo pueda presionarse una vez y no en todas las ejecuciones se presenta el error, mi pregunta es como puedo prevenir el doble disparador del trigger al presionar el botón en el formulario.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. La pregunta no tiene detalles suficientes. Por favor agrega un [mcve].